# Prime number factorization with numba

Tags: python-3.x, numba

I'm trying to make a prime number factorization algorithm working with numba but I can't get a satisfying result.

Here's my code:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from numba import jit

def DumbPrimeFactors(n):
    result_list = list()
    prime = 2
    remaining = n

    while remaining > 1:
        if remaining % prime == 0:
            result_list.append(prime)
            remaining /= prime
            prime -= 1
        prime +=1
    return result_list

start = timer()
print(DumbPrimeFactors(500000000008))
print(f"time: {timer() - start}")

start = timer()
SmartPrimeFactors = jit(DumbPrimeFactors)
print(SmartPrimeFactors(500000000008))
print(f"time: {timer() - start}")
```

When I'm executing it the numba function seems slower, so I guess it's not working the way it's suppose to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `jit(DumbPrimeFactors, nopython=True)`, you'll see an error showing you that numba is jitting the function in `object` mode because it doesn't know how to translate everything to machine code, which will not give you optimal performance. The fix is to change the line:

```
result_list = list()
```

to:

```
result_list = []
```

It appears as if the numba code that translates python to the IR (intermediate representation) doesn't know about the `list()` syntax. Then on my machine, the numba jitted version is about 7x faster than the un-jitted version. Also note that when you time numba code, the first time you run it, the time you see is the runtime + compilation time. All subsequent runs will use a cached version of the jitted code, so you'll see just the actual execution time.

Comment: Uh, this library is a little touchy ain't it? I now got a 10x speed up, thank you!

Comment: For reference, I raised an issue about this here: https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/3150